# Return 3 select results in same query window

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 queries that I need to see in the same query editor window but can't seem to figure out how Postgres wants it. I have a background in T-SQL where it's intuitive enough to run this and return 3 different result set windows for each different select query.

```
select col1, count(col2)as col2
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col2 = 'Yes'
group by col1

select col1, count(col3)as col3
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col3 = 'Yes'
group by col1

select col1, count(col4)as col4
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col4 = 'Yes'
group by col1
```

This is what I'm currently seeing

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>count1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>count2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is what I want to see

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>count1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>count2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>count1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>count3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
<th>col4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>count1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>count4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what looks the result like ? depending on the result the query would be different

Comment: The only result set it's returning is from the first query. Even when adding ; to the end of each select. I have also tried UNION and INTERSECT but it's not quite doing what I expect it to do.

Comment: please add some data  and wanted result in table form or even better as dbfiddle, i really don't understand what result you want to happen

Comment: UNION, but add another column. `select 'col2_results', col1, count.... union select 'col3_results', col1, count... select 'col4_results'....`.

Comment: Postgres runs queries individually (just like MS Access), if you want a "batch mode" like T-SQL does, then [you need to be in **PL/pgSQL mode**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) - though in this particular case because your queries have a homogenous structure you should use a `UNION` query instead of separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Since the queries have the same column output, then I would probably just UNION the queries together. Add another alias column so that you know which results are associated with which query.

```
select 'col2_results', col1, count(col2)as total
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col2 = 'Yes'
group by col1
union
select 'col3_results', col1, count(col3)as total
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col3 = 'Yes'
group by col1
union 
select 'col4_results', col1, count(col4)as total
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col4 = 'Yes'
group by col1
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your result, you should add the text of the headings as SELECT

The Order column is needed as tables and resultsets are unsorted.

If you don't want the column order, you cnaq use a CTE to remove it

```
CREATE tABLE table1 (col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT, col4 TEXT)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1,'None','None', 'Yes'),
(4,'None','None', 'Yes'),
(1,'Yes','None','None'),
(2,'Yes','None','None'),
(1,'None','Yes','None'),
(3,'None','Yes','None')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 6
> ```

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'col1' as col1, 'col2' other, 1 "Order" from table1
UNION
select col1, count(col2)::TEXT,2 as col2
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col2 = 'Yes'
group by col1
UNION
  SELECT 'col1', 'col3',3 from table1
UNION
select col1, count(col3)::TEXT as col3 , 4
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col3 = 'Yes'
group by col1
UNION
  SELECT 'col1', 'col4' , 5 from table1
UNION
select col1, count(col4)::TEXT as col4 , 6
from table1
where col1 <> 'None'
and col4 = 'Yes'
group by col1

ORDER BY "Order", col1)
SELECT col1, other FROM CTE
```

| col1 | other |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | col2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| col1 | col3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| col1 | col4 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 9
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R5ESN3Bp)